# what are some ways to load data into Cassandra from Active MQ?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra, spring-boot

my team is tasked with consuming data from Active MQ and loading them in Datastax cassandra.

they are using spring (Java) to do this.  i was wondering if there were any other ways to do this that was easier, more robust, easier to scale and maintain.

for example, is it possible to do this via spark or storm? i could not figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Camel Cassandra component](http://camel.apache.org/cassandra) since last Camel release. You could create a route from ActiveMQ to Cassandra. This is the simplest solution.

If you really want to distribute the load there is [Spark Streaming/Camel connector](http://spark-packages.org/package/synsys/spark) and a [Spark Streaming Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/8_streaming.md). So you can probably do it with Spark Streaming as well.

I can't tell about Storm.

Answer (score 0):

There is also this [Camel Cassandra component](https://github.com/joef551/camel-cql), which does seem to be more robust. If you want to keep it all within a Camel route and distribute the load, you can couple the Camel component with the [load balancer pattern](http://camel.apache.org/load-balancer.html) .